# How to display message (with switch_theme hook) after deactivating My theme?

Tags: themes, admin, hooks, actions, switch-theme

I'm able to display a message by activation of my theme with the 'new' after_switch_theme hook this way:

```
function themeActivationFunction($oldname, $oldtheme=false) {
$msg = '
    <div class="error">
        <p>The ' . get_option( 'current_theme' ) . ' theme has been ACTIVATED.</p>
    </div>';
    add_action( 'admin_notices', $c = create_function( '', 'echo "' . addcslashes( $msg, '"' ) . '";' ) );

}
add_action("after_switch_theme", "themeActivationFunction", 10 ,  2);
```

But it does not work with the swith_theme hook for deactivation of my theme. I think because by switching the theme to another one to default WordPress message overwrites my message stucking in the theme that gets deactivated and the reload of the screen deletes everything.

```
function themeDeactivationFunction($theme) {
// Lets let the admin know whats going on.
        $msg = '
    <div class="error">
        <p>Your theme has been DEACTIVATED</p>
    </div>';
    add_action( 'admin_notices', $c = create_function( '', 'echo "' . addcslashes( $msg, '"' ) . '";' ) );
}
add_action("switch_theme", "themeDeactivationFunction", 10 , 2);
```

I'm looking for a 'work around' to notify a user about deactivating my theme and the setup routine after it.

Comment: The messages are _just examples_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>It's impossible, because after deactivation your theme isn't even loaded!</strike>

It's possible, but hacky. Essentially, we unset the `action` param, load in the themes admin page & then exit before the redirect-on-success occurs.

```
add_action( 'switch_theme', 'wpse_60972_theme_deactivate_message' );
function wpse_60972_theme_deactivate_message()
{
    $msg = '
    <div class="error">
        <p>Your theme has been DEACTIVATED</p>
    </div>';

    add_action( 'admin_notices', create_function( '', 'echo "' . addcslashes( $msg, '"' ) . '";' ) );

    unset( $_GET['action'] );
    require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/themes.php';
    exit;
}
```

If the code you posted is verbatim, may I ask *why* you want do as such? WordPress has it's own notices for activation & deactivation.

Comment: I have a specific theme that should have specific pages. By activating the theme i check if there are those specific pages. If not, i create them and set some options like `show_on_front`, `page_on_front` and `page_for_posts`.

After deactivating my specific theme i want to set the pervious options and notify the user about it.

Comment: That's fine, but why are the activation/deactivation messages necessary?

Comment: For good UX... feedback is always good for user. :-)

Comment: WordPress displays activation/deactivation messages by default, there's no need for you to replicate this behaviour.

Comment: Yes, i know. But for **activation** i want something like _My-Theme is activated. Specific pages 'Wellcome' and 'News' were created. 'Wellcome' is now your front page and 'News' your posts page. Your previous settings were saved and will be reset by deactivating this theme._ And for **deactivation** i want something like _My-Theme is deactivated. Your previous settings are reseted. You can delete 'Wellcome' and 'News' by clicking **here**._

Comment: Which is why I asked if the code you posted was verbatim!

Comment: Sorry for not recognize it @TheDeadMedic. Well then... impossible is impossible. Thanks for your support guys!

Comment: Well, I found a way - see revision.

Comment: Now, that is some advanced stuff and it works as expected. Thank you very much!